# How to force a widget (dropdown box) value programmatically?

Tags: bokeh

I'm setting in place a visualization which data are driven by selections made through bokeh widgets (mainly dropdowns).
The dropdowns are linked (i.e: depending on dropdown 1 choice, dropdown2 will be filled with certain data, etc...)

I have 2 needs which tend to be the same:
I know I can get the value of a choice by using dropdown1.value (in an on_change callback) so:

- How can I **set** the value of a dropdown (and force it to display this choice) ?
- How can I reset all dropdowns to the default startup position?

  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bokeh `Dropdown` widget doesn't support displaying the value that you clicked. You would need to use [Select](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#select) widget for that.

Then like [bigreddot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406693/bigreddot) already said there is no tracking of default value but if you put your "default" value **as first** in the `options` attribute of your `Select` then you can do:

`select.value = value` to select/display a value

`select.value = null` (JS callback)

or

`select.value = None` (Python callback) to select/display the **first** value

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, or Python:

```
widget.value = new_value
```

There's nothing that keeps track of the initial values you set. You will have to record them and set them as above when you want them to reset.